# Why my program doesnt get delayed for 1 second?

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

Im doing a random walker program in python and using **Pygame** for the graphics.

The program is working fine, however i want that in every `for loop` at the end of the code it should delay the program for 1 second, so the program completes itself in a matter of seconds, but rather i can see the continous random walk.

So when i add `time.sleep(1)` at the end of the code, it instead makes the program run slower and it doesnt draw a circle every second:

```
import pygame
import random
import time


#Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800)) # Width and Height 

startX = 400
startY = 400


def returnRandomNumber():
    options = [1,-1]
    
    random_sample = random.choice(options)

    return random_sample

def returnRandomInt():
    random_sample = random.randint(0,255)

    return random_sample


running = True
while running:
    #update display
    pygame.display.update()


    for x in range(10000):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (returnRandomInt(),returnRandomInt(),returnRandomInt()), (startX, startY), 2, 2)
        if startX <= 0:
            startX += 1
        elif startX >= 800:
            startX += -1
        else:
            startX += returnRandomNumber()
        
        if startY <= 0:
            startY += 1
        elif startY >= 800:
            startY += -1
        else:
            startY += returnRandomNumber()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Why is this ocurring? or how can i make the program to draw a circle and then delay for x seconds and continue running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting update and sleep inside your for loop, so your display would update after every iteration:

```
while running:
#update display
pygame.display.update()


for x in range(10000):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (returnRandomInt(),returnRandomInt(),returnRandomInt()), (startX, startY), 2, 2)
    if startX <= 0:
        startX += 1
    elif startX >= 800:
        startX += -1
    else:
        startX += returnRandomNumber()
    
    if startY <= 0:
        startY += 1
    elif startY >= 800:
        startY += -1
    else:
        startY += returnRandomNumber()
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: thanks! that actually worked! however i noticed that after some seconds the program crashes, it also happened before but i thought that it was because of the infinite while loop, any ideas?

Comment: You’re drawing a lot of circles - 10000 per iteration, and it doesn’t stop. So you might want to focus on this piece of code and draw less circles- perhaps stop after a few.

Comment: i'd imagined that, however before putting the time.sleep it draw thousands of circles before crashing, but after putting time.sleep(1) it draws like 10 circles and then crashes.

Comment: Maybe python lags, but the important thing is that you’re drawing infinite circles, so you’re crashing the script.

Comment: Yeah i dont know if it is a python or pygame issue, thanks for your input it worked. Yet i tried one last thing i added a counter variable to the program so that every for loop it adds 1 and when it reached the same number as the range in the for loop. it will stop the program.  So i noticed how it the program crashes and it stops drawing, but after a few seconds it closes and for a brief second i can see the other x circles getting drawn before it closes.

Comment: Still, you’re probably drawing too much circles

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote and accept it with the green v mark :)

Comment: done, thanks buddy. any tips or particular project to get better at programming?

Comment: Practice makes perfect :)

Comment: Sorry, but your answer will not work on every system because you do not handle the events in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

The time.sleep (1) needs to swap places with the pygame.display.update ()

Code:
import pygame
import random
import time

## Initialize the pygame

pygame.init()

## create the screen

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))  # Width and Height

startX = 400
startY = 400

def returnRandomNumber():
options = [1, -1]

```
random_sample = random.choice(options)

return random_sample
```

def returnRandomInt():
random_sample = random.randint(0, 255)

```
return random_sample
```

running = True
while running:
# update display
time.sleep(1)

```
for x in range(10000):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (returnRandomInt(), returnRandomInt(), returnRandomInt()), (startX, startY), 2, 2)
    if startX <= 0:
        startX += 1
    elif startX >= 800:
        startX += -1
    else:
        startX += returnRandomNumber()

    if startY <= 0:
        startY += 1
    elif startY >= 800:
        startY += -1
    else:
        startY += returnRandomNumber()
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer will not work on every system because you do not handle the events in the inner loop.

Comment: Hello, what will be the correct answer?}